# Bitcoin's error (debug file)

Tags: bitcoin-core, error

Bitcoin synchronized approximately on 60% and today in the morning I saw this error: "Error: a fatal error occured (see details in the debug.log)". Here's my debug log: [debug log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BQ-3u1RfFT5r5hFDlTTlrG5ffdlOQsjT/view?usp=sharing)
Kindly help me to solve this problem.

[image: error's screenshot]

---

Bitcoin was installed on DataD. But I also see Bitcoin folder on Sys C.
Today in the morning there really was lack of space on Sys C.
I cleaned some space, and you can see the screenshots - free space underlined in green, the capacity of disks - in blue.
[image: data d]
[image: sys c]
So when there was 3Gb free space on Sys C, everything worked. Now I have the same error. Kindly tell me what else it's possible to do? 60% synchronization it's not everything, but a lot of time was spent on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the critical error:

```
2018-01-07 10:22:45 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Deserialize or I/O error - CAutoFile::read: fread failed at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=693, nPos=38137925)
2018-01-07 10:22:57 *** Failed to read block
```

I would 1st check if you have run out of disk space?